# How to secure Nexus with the help of docker-compose file

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have tried simple docker-compose file without securing it. Now I want to secure it with ssl how to modify my docker-compose file without using Nginx. I have created a volume for certs(/var/volume/nexus/certs:/certs:ro) and mapped it with the volume of nexus.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you